# How to scan characters printed on a physical paper using camera PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am building a mobile application using PhoneGap. I am trying to scan a code printed on a newspaper using the camera and convert it into a string object and then search for that code in the database.

I am using HTML5, CSS3, Javascript, JQuery-Mobile. I am not sure were to start... this is different from a bar-code scanner since i am not scanning a qr code but instead just few random numbers/characters printed on the news paper ?

Example 123fr4563

Scan the above code using camera ?

Comment: search for "ocr javascript"